# Adb Shell InputText too long

Tags: android, shell, adb

I've this application into which the input text is passed through adb shell , now the problem is whenever i type command :

./adb shell input text 'Khay'

works perfectly fine and it display<"Khay"> it in a text-box in the application as it is supposed to be . but when i pass command that is very long something like :

```
./adb shell input text ' http://stagingapi.something.com/v2/api.php?apikey=2323214\&appid=32432\&imei=324234 ........................................................
```

is the text is this much longer it gives me an error

error:service name too long.

now i've a 2part questions.

1. can i somehow pass this long text using adb shell .
2. If option1 is not possible then what is it that i can do about passing this long input text

Comment: make sure your text string contains no spaces. replace all spaces with `%s`

Comment: Yea did that too already.  Well i've come up with a temporary and simple solution , to pass the input in 3 parts , and the string just gets append one part to the other

Answer (score 6):

A work around for the problem is to write the long command to a local shell file, push the file using `adb push` and then execute it on the device using `sh`.

So instead of executing:

```
adb shell input text ' http://...some.really.long.command...'
```

Do this instead:

```
echo "input text ' http://...some.really.long.command...'" > longcommand.sh
adb push longcommand.sh /data/local/tmp
adb shell sh /data/local/tmp/longcommand.sh
```

Comment: This saved my life. I don't want to root my device and didn't remember I could `sh file.sh` instead of `./file.sh`. Just one remark: I don't think `chmod +x file.sh` is needed for this to work.

Comment: It shouldn't be needed, as you are not running the script directly. Making it executable is needed if you want to run it by itself, though in that case you need the shebang statement at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the string length that is your problem, it is the special character handling.

```
Best to run your string through a converter (to add escape codes),
there are quite a few characters that input does not like:
<pre>
 ( ) < > | ; & * \ ~ 
</pre>
and space escaped with %s .
<pre>
    char * convert(char * trans_string)
    {
        char *s0 = replace(trans_string, '\\', "\\\\");
        free(trans_string);
        char *s = replace(s0, '%', "\\\%");
        free(s0);
        char *s1 = replace(s, ' ', "%s");//special case for SPACE
        free(s);
        char *s2 = replace(s1, '\"', "\\\"");
        free(s1);
        char *s3 = replace(s2, '\'', "\\\'");
        free(s2);
        char *s4 = replace(s3, '\(', "\\\(");
        free(s3);
        char *s5 = replace(s4, '\)', "\\\)");
        free(s4);
        char *s6 = replace(s5, '\&', "\\\&");
        free(s5);
        char *s7 = replace(s6, '\<', "\\\<");
        free(s6);
        char *s8 = replace(s7, '\>', "\\\>");
        free(s7);
        char *s9 = replace(s8, '\;', "\\\;");
        free(s8);
        char *s10 = replace(s9, '\*', "\\\*");
        free(s9);
        char *s11 = replace(s10, '\|', "\\\|");
        free(s10);
        char *s12 = replace(s11, '\~', "\\\~");
        //this if un-escaped gives current directory !
        free(s11);
        char *s13 = replace(s12, '\¬', "\\\¬");
        free(s12);
        char *s14 = replace(s13, '\`', "\\\`");
        free(s13);
    //  char *s15 = replace(s14, '\¦', "\\\¦");
    //  free(s14);
        return s14;
}

(code from inputer native binary: interactive converter for input).
```